# convert python2.6 cantera1.8 to python2.7 cantera2.2

Tags: python

I am new on chemical network model. Currently I am converting a previous student python code to adapt the new version in the lab as titled.

firstly, a gas mixture from mechanism (pre defined) is defined

```
gas_mix = ct.import_phases(mech,['gas'])
```

then, I want to get the number of the species and use cantera nSpecies

```
nsp = gas_mix.nSpecies()
```

and I got the error message as

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'nSpecies'

Also I tried:

```
nsp = gas_mix.n_species
```

and it also shows

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute

Would you please kindly help me on this ?
Thank you and best regards,
YouBe

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `import_phases` returns a list of objects--either a list of "gas mix" or just "gas" objects. I'm not really sure because this is very specific to the program you're working with.

Anyway, try looping over the values in the `gas_mix` and see if you can call the `nSpecies()` method or access the `n_species` attribute:

```
gas_mix = ct.import_phases(mech,['gas'])
for gm in gas_mix:
    print(gm.nSpecies())
    # or you can try this:
    print(gm.n_species)
```

Maybe that will get you closer to what you want.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately I got the same error message.  AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'set'   I am making an external loop on counting the species and put it in this code as numbers for a fast solution.

Answer (score 0):

The function `import_phases` returns a list, which is useful for the case where you want to import multiple phase definitions from the same file, e.g.

```
mixtures = ct.import_phases(mech, ['gas1', 'gas2'])
```

where both `mixtures[0]` and `mixtures[2]` will then be a single phase definition. If you only want to define a single phase, it is easier to write:

```
gas_mix = ct.Solution(mech,'gas')
```

Or, if the mechanism file only contains one phase definition, just

```
gas_mix = ct.Solution(mech)
```

From here, you should be able to access the number of species as

```
gas_mix.n_species
```

Many of the details of migrating from the old to new Cantera interfaces are described in the documentation page "[Migrating from the Old Python Module](http://cantera.github.io/docs/sphinx/html/cython/migrating.html)".

Comment: sorry for the late reply and thank you for your answer. I found that I used the wrong updated version of nSpecies that should be .n_species without (). Now it seems not this issue but other issues then.